# Is there a benefit to embedding microformat information in the HTML for a web app?

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, usability, microformats

Is there a benefit to implementing [micro-formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/microformats) (or `itemscope`) in the [html](/questions/tagged/html) for a web app?  So far it only looks like it is useful for [seo](/questions/tagged/seo) and my web app is behind a login screen, so I will not have to worry about that.  Are there any plugins or browsers which automatically process the information.

Or as [unor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1591669/unor) proposed, is there a benefit in adding structured data to non-public sites?

Comment: You link to the documentation of Microformats, but `itemscope` is from Microdata.

Comment: Hmm... I am new to this.  Is one supported more than the other?

Comment: Can’t be answered in general, some support this, some support that. And there’s also RDFa and JSON-LD … So I guess your question could be generalized to: *Is there a benefit in adding structured data to non-public sites?* -- But how could this be answered? There are of course tools (like browser extensions) that make use of structured data, but the question is at which point you would consider this to be a benefit.

Comment: @unor , what are some of the popular extensions which use structured data?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/microformats/oalbifknmclbnmjlljdemhjjlkmppjjl?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you generalize the question like [unor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1591669/unor) proposed:

> Is there a benefit in adding structured data to non-public sites?

It has got a definit advantage! For someone with *visual disability* it is easier to navigate through sites if micro-formats are implemented. If there is a possibility that someone with a screen reader will use the application it worth the effort. Not to mention that it is a **one-time task with a long term positive effect**. I think it is a good thing to proactively thrive to serve all kind of user.

Answer to the original question: browsers do not have to process those information, but some advanced technology could use it in the browser like [preload](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/02/preload-what-is-it-good-for/). There was a research at my University about which pages to reload and those were using this feature. (Eg: in free time of the processor the browser plugin preloaded home to enhance the browsing experience.)

Comment: Actually, we have a lot of users who are blink or seeing impaired and my app already works well in with screen readers (like JAWS and the Mac VoiceOver).  I was really looking for a cost benefit analysis of doing the work vs added benefit.

Comment: If it is already performing well with screen readers you could test it with http://webaim.org/simulations/screenreader. I still recommend to implement it since the preload functionality could be a really nice feture to have.